# Clipping with added "buffer"

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip, select-by-location, within

i want to Clip my Point data (Bus Stations) through a Polygon (the City area, highlighted in the picture) but if possible include any Point data which is e.g. 500 meters around the city boundary. So People living at the red X would choose bus station a instead of b, which is within the city but closer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, so your Question needs to present a problem and ask a question. All you have here is a task. Please [Edit] the Question to state what have you tried, and where you are stuck. Note that points *can't* be clipped, only selected. if you want to model the boundary with a buffer only for points close to the boundary, select and buffer the points, then union and dissolve.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Buffer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) your city by 500m
2. Use your buffered city to [Clip](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm) your point layer
3. Use that resulting layer of city+500m bus stations for your analysis.

Comment: Or you could just SelectByLocation and use the selected layer *in situ*.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcgisPro you can use the *[Select by location tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/navigation/select-features-by-location.htm)* on your point layer with the realitionship *Within distance* and the city layer as *Selecting Feature*. Than Export Features with the selected rows activeted, which is default setting or create a *[Selection Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/selection-layers.htm)* in memory or rather use the selction for an other geoprocessing tool.

[image]

There are three different selection options for *within*:

[select-layer-by-location](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm)

> WITHIN_A_DISTANCE—The features in the input layer will be selected if
> they are within the specified distance (using Euclidean distance) of a
> selecting feature. Use the search_distance parameter to specify the
> distance.

> WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D—The features in the input layer will be
> selected if they are within a specified distance of a selecting
> feature in three-dimensional space. Use the search_distance parameter
> to specify the distance.

> WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_GEODESIC—The features in
> the input layer will be selected if they are within a specified
> distance of a selecting feature. Distance between features will be
> calculated using a geodesic formula that takes into account the
> curvature of the spheroid and correctly handles data near and across
> the dateline and poles. Use the search_distance parameter to specify
> the distance.